# NSString editing by many View Controllers?

Tags: xcode, string, printing, global

I want to print a NSString in my TextView in the mainViewController. But this command should come from a second ViewController. I declared a string in my mainViewController.h but I need this string in secondViewController.m! (The text should be printed in mainViewController). When I want to access to this string, it says Xcode does not know this variable. How can i create a string/variable, which I can edit and print from all of my ViewControllers(xib!)?

Comment: How about making the variable public static? That way, no instance is required of the mainViewController?

Comment: I wouldn't know; Obj-C is out of my comfort-zone. However, a quick google gave me something like `extern` or `static`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to share a model between two view controllers.  This is the correct MVC approach so that all that is required is for one of the view controller to change the value in the model and all the other view controllers will be notified and can update their respective views:

Please look at [this excellent article](http://cupsofcocoa.com/2011/09/10/design-patterns-key-value-observing/) on how this should be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

just declare that NSString variable in AppDelegate & access in any ViewController through the sharedApplication method .in your case assign value to it in secondViewController & access that value in mainViewController

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLOg(@"Nsstring value=%@",appDelegate.stringVariable);
```

assigning value:`appDelegate.stringVariable=@"fromSecondViewController");`

Comment: doesn't work or i'm stupid :/
when i take this in my AppDelegate i get this errors:



first line of code:
(ERROR) Initializer element is not a compile-time constant



second line of code:
(WARNING) Type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
(WARNING) Incompatible redeclaration of library function 'NSLog'
(ERROR) Expected parameter declarator
(ERROR) Expected ')'